# whonix qemu/kvm maximum memory usage

Tags: memory, kvm

I am using the newest Whonix on qemu/kvm. 
Why is the memory usage always at Maximum for W-Gateway (max 2024 MiB) and W-Workstation (4048 MiB)? 
I have other VMs (debian) installed as well, and it is not using the maximum memory there.

Answer (score 0):

I watched some videos about linux process management. Installed htop and saw that there is actually no problem with the memory in the machine. It is just in the virtual machine management window statistics that memory usage is displayed at max. Even if my autistic genes rebel at the the thought that sth is not displayed correctly, I will use that to train myself to live with that flaw. Maybe I will learn to fix it one day.